# Looking for constant values for DAO.Field.Type

Tags: vbscript, dao

I have need of using VBS in conjunction with the DAO.Field.Type methods and properties.  Since I am using VBS I do not have access to the constants displayed on this page and I can't find a good resource that will tell me what they are.

Most specifically this MSDN article lists the constant names, but I don't know what their values are, and I would appreciate finding out what they are.

[Field.Type Property (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845405%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Thanks,

Sean W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Microsoft Office? Here's one way you can find them.

1. Open any Office product.
2. Hit `ALT+F11` to open the VBA editor.
3. From the `Tools` menu, select `References...`.
4. Find the reference entitled `Microsoft DAO X.X Object Library`, check it, and click OK.
5. Hit `F2` to bring up `Object Browser`.
6. In the top drop-down, choose the `DAO` library.
7. In the 2nd drop-down, type your constant name (e.g., `dbBigInt`) and hit [Enter] to search.
8. Select the proper item from the search results.
9. Near the status bar is a pane that describes the selected item. It will show you the constant's value.